# Particle on a banked curve with no external force

Tags: classical-mechanics

Suppose a particle starts at the bottom of a banked curve and is given an initial velocity perpendicular to the lower, inner radius. If there are no external forces on the particle apart from the normal with the curve (no gravity, friction, etc.), does the particle travel in a helix up and eventually off the banked curve?

I thought of this while doing a textbook mechanics problem and am having trouble writing down an expression for the normal force in Newton’s 2nd law to demonstrate this. It seems to me the normal force could be written as a function of position or time, and I’m not sure if a Cartesian coordinate system (with respect to the ground, I don’t know how you’d set it up wrt the curve) is appropriate.

If someone has even a hint about how to write this down, I’d appreciate it very much!

Comment: So the banked curve is part of a cone? The initial velocity is perpendicular to the curve, so straight up the cone? There is no gravity, so there is no maximum height the ball can travel?

Comment: You’re right I didn’t specify the complete geometry. A banked enclosed curve with some maximum height to the ramp. So the curve has a lower, smallest circumference in contact with the ground and an upper, largest  circumference at some max height. Like a NASCAR track but perfectly circular.

Comment: With no gravity, if you start a ball straight up a cone it will go forever. With gravity, you could figure out a maximum height from energy. If you add a sideways velocity to that, it will travel around the cone, but the height at any instant won't be affected. You might think about components of forces and velocity to see why.

Comment: I think I see where I’m confused. If the normal force is perpendicular to the curve at any position on the curve, and you break down the vector into components wrt the ground, one of those force components is vertical and the other is pointing outward from the curve. Why does this vertical force component not cause vertical acceleration?

Comment: I think I see it now. The vertical force component wrt the ground would lift it off the ramp, removing the contact force no? So there’s no net force parallel to and up the ramp. Thanks for your help!